# customizing the keyboard height and width in iphone using objective-c

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want my customized keyboard in iphone with height and width that i want.

Answer (score 4):

Only orientation and type of keyboard (numeric, alphanumeric etc) are customizable. **Width and height are not.**

For more detailed information on all you can do with the keyboard, read the [iPhone Application Programming Guide, section about the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TextandWeb/TextandWeb.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH20-SW3).

Answer (score 0):

For consistent user experience, to my knowledge the iPhone keyboard height cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard itself isn't directly managed by the user. The keyboard is messaged by objects conforming to the 'UITextInputTraits' protocol, or reacted to by 'observers' using 'notifications'. So the type of keyboard is requested by a given text field object, etc. and greater detail can be found in the link provided by Kriem, this is the most helpful documentation I've read on the subject.